# rest service and grpc service performance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grpc

I have created service using rest api and grpc and I am using hibernate for backend. datasource is same just I want check how fast the grpc is as compared to rest api so I am fetching 5000 record from table which contains almost 200 column.so after fetching data in both rest and grpc. I have observed that both have almost same metrics
For rest api it take 20.50s
For grpc api it take 21.20s
I have tested using postman.
even grpc is little bit slow almost 1 sec I have used uranary in grpc. So I want to know in which way we can find the performance better as compared to rest api

I was expecting grpc would be faster but performance is almost same

Comment: what about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146721/how-are-protocol-buffers-faster-than-xml-and-json/52148242#52148242) does it answer to your question ?

Comment: if you're talking 20s vs 21s, the bottleneck isn't your protocol, its how you're hitting the database and prepping the data. 5000 x 200 is a lot of data. Doubtful you need to be fetching that much at once. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For testing purpose I have been fetching that much record to identify how fast the grpc is as compared to rest api. In postman I have observed that grpc response is same as rest. Yes I know that data base fetching part will be same in rest and grpc but grpc send the response in binary so I think it should send response fast as compared to rest. Is their any other way to test it to find the performance